# My facebook site app is very slow

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using a dedicated server.
1gbps port.

There are the following code (which connects with facebook)

```
    if($_POST['friend_id'] != 0) {
        $query = "SELECT uid, first_name, pic, sex FROM user WHERE uid = ".$_POST['friend_id'];
    }
    else {
        $query = "SELECT uid, first_name, pic, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() order by rand() limit 1)";
    }

    $query = urlencode($query);
    $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'. 'fql?q='.$query. '&access_token=' . $access_token;
    $response = $facebook->api("/fql?q=$query");
    $data = $response['data'];
```

Then I use the uid to get the photo of the user.

```
    $img = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$friend_id.'/picture?type=normal');
    $imagesurse1 = $friend_id.uniqid().'.jpg';
    file_put_contents($imagesurse1, $img);

    $img = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_id.'/picture?type=normal');
    $imagesurse2 = $user_id.uniqid().'.jpg';
    file_put_contents($imagesurse2, $img);
```

These code is taking 10 secs to xx seconds. xx reached upto 60.
What could be the problem.

It is a site app. Site doesnot have "https"

Comment: Try to use cURL whenever possible. It might speed up some of your outbound connections - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555523/file-get-contents-vs-curl-what-has-better-performance

Comment: Tried curl now. But it didn't download photo on the server. I should be making mistakes. Is it possible to download indirect images using curl?

Comment: I tried curl now. I don't see much difference. How do i download 10 profile images without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is normally pretty slow. Can't you cache your results?
Can you test your code piece by piece so you can figure out which part is causing the trouble?

Comment: I tried to test the code. It is api call which is taking different no. of seconds everytime.

Comment: But won't people change their profile photos and profile names?

Comment: That's true but you can cache this for a couple of hours or a day or something.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can say that Facebook's API is kind of slow. You should benchmark your page and what takes the most time. But I bet it's the Facebook API call.

Do you really have to download all the pictures? Can't you just use the OpenGraph-URL (`https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user_id.'/picture?type=normal`) as HTML image tag?

Is there any possibility to make this call asynchronous with AJAX?

Comment: Yes, I am using HTML image tag at many places. Here i really neeed to download that image to generate some images.

Answer (score 0):

Start at the start: debugging the issue. It's quite possible it's just that the Facebook API is slow, which would indeed cause your script to wait until all the resources are loaded, but those results can be cached. Another issue might be that your queries are simply taking too long. Try benchmarking with XDebug to see what the slow parts of your script are, and see if you have the correct indexes for your queries. For example, the second query can possibly be optimised by using a `join` instead a subquery.

Comment: Can you post an example for `join`. I have never used it with facebook api. I will try it.

Comment: @MaheshKumar It's not specific to the Facebook API, it's a different way to get the same results from a different, faster query.

Comment: @Mahesh Have you attempted Googling the words "join sql" yet? It's not that hard... Without seeing your datamodel, I can only guess that the following works: `SELECT user.uid, user.first_name, user.pic, user.sex FROM friend LEFT JOIN user ON user.uid = friend.uid2 WHERE friend.uid1=me() ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;`